# Cauliflower: mildew, or just darkening with age?

Tags: vegetables, mold, freshness

Unless the cauliflower in the market is *extremely* fresh, I usually see at least a couple specimens with tiny blackish freckles on the bumpy "flower" surface.

[image: see photo]

I have assumed the spots were mildew, and tried to avoid them. I even shave that part of the cauliflower a little bit (for esthetics) if I get a head that has them. But they don't seem to taste moldy and aren't ever fuzzy. So I'm curious: is this really mildew, or just a color change that occurs as the cauliflower ages?

Comment: Googled ... found this http://www.dvo.com/newsletter/weekly/2014/07-25-520/cooknart5.html  ...says it is a mark left by oxidation.

Comment: If this is the usual look, I would start looking for a different market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just oxidation from the cauliflower aging. In the state the cauliflower in the picture is in, I wouldn't even bother removing the spots unless you're preparing it in a way that makes you think they'd be unsightly. If the curd/florets are still firm, you're good.